# how to display a view in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm totally new to `Django`, and I'm trying to understand how does it work (I'm more used to `PHP` and `Spring` frameworks.
I have a project called `testrun` and inside it an app called `graphs`, so my `views.py` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
   return HttpResponse("Hello, World. You're at the graphs index.")
```

then, in `graphs/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from graphs import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

finally, at `testrun/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'testrun.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^graphs/', include('graphs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

However, when I try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphs/` I get:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphs/
Using the URLconf defined in testrun.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, graphs/, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

What am I doing wrong that I can't get that simple message to be displayed in the browser?

Comment: Have you added `graphs` to your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: can you show us what the file tree for your app directory looks like? seems like you are importing the wrong `urls.py`

Comment: The first argument to patterns should be a `''`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at mako if you like PhP and it will be an easier transition. Also you may want to play with a micro framework too,  django, in my experience, has a bit of a learning curve. It's usually good to chew on one thing at a time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, the first argument to `patterns()` function is

> a prefix to apply to each view function

You can find more information here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#syntax-of-the-urlpatterns-variable

Therefore in `graphs/urls.py` you need to fix the patterns call like so:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', # <-- note the `'',`
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```